# Certificate error using IMAP in PHP

Tags: php, imap

I used up all possible combinations of hostname but I always either get a certificate error or just IMAP connection broken.

> Certificate failure for imap.froiden.com: Server name does not match
>   certificate: /O=imap.mailhostbox.com/OU=Go to
>   https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html/OU=Thawte SSL123
>   certificate/OU=Domain Validated/CN=imap.mailhostbox.com

Hostname which I used is '`{imap.froiden.com}INBOX`'. ANy suggestion to solve this error?

Comment: the cert was issued for `imap.mailhostbox.com` - for SSL connections, the requested hostname and the hostname the cert was issued for MUST match, or you're going to get these warnings/errors. Hostname mismatches (in a malicious setting) mean someone's trying to spoof/forge something.

Comment: @MarcB Well, I tried every combination but it doesnt work like **imap.froiden.com:993/imap/ssl**. Is there anything I need to configure on my host?

Comment: You should be using imap.mailboxhost.com:993/imap/ssl, assuming that the cert is right and it really is being served up from a machine named imap.mailhostbox.com

Comment: @MarcB: results in a timeout.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The certificate is plain invalid. You should either connect to `imap.mailboxhost.com:993/imap/ssl` or contact the administrator of the mail server and ask for a valid certificate.

Note that while you *can* use the connection string `imap.froiden.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert` to skip certificate validation, you *should* not do so as that flag will allow any [*Man In The Middle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacker to read and write your email.

Comment: Thanks, the `{imap.example.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX` did work

Comment: Thanks  {example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert} INBOX did work for me. I am realy hapy. I want to hug you.

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm this is working well:

```
$mb = imap_open("{phoenix.srv.spletnasoba.si:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}","username", "password" );

$emails = array();
$messageCount = imap_num_msg($mb);
for( $MID = 1; $MID <= $messageCount; $MID++ )
{

    $EmailHeaders = imap_headerinfo( $mb, $MID );
    foreach($EmailHeaders as $key => $value) {
        if (validateEmail($value)) {
            $emails[$value] = $key;
            echo $value."\n";
        }
    }
}



function validateEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using gmail, make sure you turn on "Allow access for less secure apps" in the account settings page of your google account for you to be able to access your gmail account using imap_open()