# Certificate issu while making imap work on linux localhost

Tags: ssl, certificate, localhost, imap

I can't make `imap` work on local host this is the code i'm trying to execute:

```
<?php
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '********@gmail.com';
$password = '****************';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

and this is the error i get

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php on line 7
Cannot connect to Gmail: Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Notice: Unknown: Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: As the error message says, you have an SSL error here. You should probably post it with an ssl/openssl tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect gmail through php imap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242455/connect-gmail-through-php-imap)

Comment: @legoscia doesn't work what exist in that answer

Comment: Eugh, PHP really needs a "This is how you make SSL connections secure" guide somewhere.  The number of times this comes up is ridiculous.

Comment: @Max do you know how can i make this code work