# Bluehost: PHPMailer save sent message in Sent Items

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, imap, bluehost

I'm trying to send an email with the help of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), everything works fine except now I want to have a copy of the send mail in `Sent Items`.

The website is currently hosted in [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/). I tried following the example of [PHPMailer - GMail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) but I'm stuck on which path should I specify.

From the example of [PHPMailer - GMail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) the path for `Sent Items` is:

> {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail

I don't know what path should I specify. Everything works fine in my code, only the path for the sent item is missing.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$username = 'john@mydomain.com';
$password = 'password';

function save_mail( $mail ) {
    //path or folder for sent items
    $path = "{imap.mydomain.com:993/imap/ssl}[...]/..."; //what exactly is the path for my sent item.

    //Tell your server to open an IMAP connection using the same username and password as you used for SMTP
    $imapStream = imap_open( $path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password );
    $result = imap_append( $imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage() );
    imap_close( $imapStream );
    return $result;
}

function send(){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $username;
    $mail->Password = $password;
    $mail->setFrom( $username, 'John Doe' );
    $mail->addAddress( 'someone@example.com', 'David Doe' );
    $mail->Subject = 'TEST SUBJECT';
    $mail->msgHTML('<b>TEST</b>');
    $mail->AltBody = 'TEST';

    if ( !$mail->send() ) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
        if (save_mail($mail)) {
            echo "Message saved!";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Use the imap_list function to list your folders.  The Sent Messages folder differs by language in Gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max) for the idea of [imap_list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php) function.

This gives me the list of a path for my mail directories.

```
  $host = '{imap.mydomain.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}';

  $mail = 'support@mydomain.com';
  $pass = 'password';


  $mbox = imap_open($host, $mail, $pass, OP_HALFOPEN)
      or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$list = imap_list($mbox, $host, "*");
if (is_array($list)) {
    foreach ($list as $val) {
        echo imap_utf7_decode($val) . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "imap_list failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
}

imap_close($mbox);

?>
```

using the `{imap.mydomain.com}` or `{imap.mydomain.com:993/imap/ssl}`gives me an error of:

> can't connect: Certificate failure for imap.mydomain.com: Server
>   name does not match certificate: /OU=Domain Control
>   Validated/OU=Hosted by BlueHost.Com, INC/OU=PositiveSSL
>   Wildcard/CN=*.bluehost.com

Certificate issue, luckily I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891729/certificate-error-using-imap-in-php) and I end up using the following host:

> {imap.mydomain.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}

and the path I'm looking to forward the sent mail into sent items is:

> {imap.mydomain.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent