# php imap working locally but not on hosting: Server name does not match certificate

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

The issue is i'm trying to get the last email from my email using php, and it works fine locally. But then I uploaded the script to the client's server, and It's refusing every time. The logs show this:

```
[12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {<mail>:143/imap}INBOX in /path/triggerCall.php on line 2
[12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_headers() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/triggerCall.php on line 7
[12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_num_msg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/triggerCall.php on line 14
[12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_header() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/triggerCall.php on line 16
[12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_fetchbody() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/triggerCall.php on line 20
[12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/triggerCall.php on line 40
```

imap_errors show this:

> Certificate failure for : Server name does not match
>   certificate: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by HostGator.com,
>   LLC./OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hostclear.com"

I repeat, it works locally, but i get this on the live server. What could be causing this?

This is the code:

```
$inbox = imap_open('{<mail>:993/imap}', '<username>', '<password>');
$headers = imap_headers($inbox);
$last = imap_num_msg($inbox);
$header = imap_header($inbox, $last); 
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $last,1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certificate error using IMAP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891729/certificate-error-using-imap-in-php)

Comment: @mitkosoft unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Your error message does not match your code: [12-Feb-2020 08:43:21 location] PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {<mail>:***143***/imap}INBOX in /path/triggerCall.php on line 2

Comment: That error is shown in the logs. The error i get with imap_errors() is: Certificate failure for : Server name does not match certificate: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by HostGator.com, LLC./OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hostclear.com"