# PHP is certificate error when using imap open imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl

Tags: php, ssl, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to use PHP imap to connect to a gmail box.  My connection line is:

```
$connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'username', 'password')
```

It then gives me an error saying: "PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /sbc/phpscripts/lar/gm2.php on line 12 Cannot connect to Gmail: Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: self signed certificate: /OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalidPHP Notice:  Unknown: Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: self signed certificate: /OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0"

I can get it to connect using the novalidate-cert flag and enabling the allow less secure apps in gmail, but that is not secure and every solution that I find says to do that.  Gmail says "allow less secure apps" will not be allowed after 5/30/22, so this is not an option and I suspect this is a issue that is going to cause a lot of people a problem in the near future.

I am running on rhel using php 8.

Can someone please explain how to get this set up so that I can connect securely to gmail?  Do I need to install a certificate on my linux server?  If so, how do I do that?

Comment: "Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: self signed certificate" - that sounds strange. Why should Google not provide properly signed certificates?

Comment: Do you have any sort of firewall, virus scanner or similar between your machine and the internet perhaps, one that messes with certificates in an attempt to peek into encrypted traffic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certificate error using IMAP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891729/certificate-error-using-imap-in-php)

Comment: RHEL and PHP 8 do not matter, while unable to present a suitable certificate of any trusted CA. Maybe setup an A entry in DNS and install `certbot`?

Comment: Martin, that does not.  I am trying to connect to gmail.  It is really surprising to me that there is not an example of how to setup and connect securely to gmail using php imap.  Maybe it is not possible, but I can't find that anywhere either.

Comment: It looks to me like either PHP or some sort of firewall is not setting SNI properly in the connection, so Google is returning a default certificate.  I don't know how you would fix it. Or you have an MITM TLS proxy (common in corporate environments) also which needs SNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'username', 'password')

Add the novalidate-cert parameter and it should work

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891729/certificate-error-using-imap-in-php already contains that hint